# Randomly select image an from directory using php and use its filename for a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, random, filenames

I have a directory of images which are all named *.jpg, where * is the ID of each record in a MySQL table. e.g. 1394.jpg

What I'd like to be able to do is pull 5 random images from that directory using PHP and for each image, then query the MySQL table for records matching that ID / image filename, so I can then display details of each record.

The part I am looking for some guidance on is how to a) randomly choose 5 images using php, then b) identifying the filenames.  Once I have the filename as a variable, I am sure I should be able to write the MySQL query.  It's the PHP element I'm struggling with.

Could anyone offer any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file info in your db is update-to-date regarding the image files in your file system, you can get the 5 random filename ids along with other info directly from the db:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM image_files ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5';
```

This will return you file ids along with other info you have there in the table.

EDIT: Apparently all files in db does not exist in file system. So below is updated answer:

```
// Get files info from db in random order
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM image_files ORDER BY RAND()';
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Pick first 5 files that does exist in file system
$five_files=Array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $filepath = '/dir/images/'.$row['id'].'.jpg';
  if (is_file($filepath)) {
      $five_files[] = $row;
      if (count($five_files) == 5) break;
  } 
}

// This will have info on five randomly picked files from db that does exist
print_r($five_files);
```

Comment: This is how I started, but only about 10% of the records in the table have images, so I need the query to ignore the records which don't have images.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Ok then just get all the images in random order (without LIMIT clause) and pick first 5 files that do exists in the file system.

Comment: How would I use PHP to limit it to the first five?

Comment: I have updated the answer. You will need to fix up the db field names.

Comment: Good to know. Can you please accept this answer in that case?

Comment: Is there a reason that when doing the count to 5, it only returns 4 results? Likewise if 1 is specified, it returns no results?

Comment: Are you referring to `if (count($five_files) == 5) break;` bit? In which case it should return 5 result when that condition is met since it means that the array holds 5 entries.

Answer (score 1):

I'll do that, first getting all the images of the folder

```
$files = glob("$dir/*.{jpg,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

Then, I'll get one (you can make a loop) random pic using `array_rand`, like this

```
$file = array_rand($files); // You can check if is repeated or something too
```

Finally, you can `preg_replace` the name of the file to get only the name (without extension) and query to your DB with that name... (Maybe there are other ways, but this is simple and fast)

Comment: Trying this, and it seems to be working fine - but every now and then it seems to pulling a filename which doesn't any image in the directory?

Comment: Can you explain the problem a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, We will do it in these steps :

1. Get File Name Lists from the required Directory

> Function : `scandir()` look for more details [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

2. Store in Array
3. Get Random 5 Data

> Function `array_rand()` look for more details [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

4. For Each File Run Query For Details

> Loop - Foreach() - Store MySQL-fetched-data in multi-dimensional Array

5. Display

Comment: I think it will be much more efficient if you fetch random 5 file data from MySQL using Rand() Than from directory. Thanks & Regards